# Mutually Exclusive Events Probability

Tags: probability

"A weather forecaster states that the probability of rain is $\frac35$, the probability of lightning is $\frac25$, and the probability of both is $\frac15$. What is the probability of a sporting event being canceled due to rain or lightning?"

How do I solve this problem? Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 3):

There's a lovely formula you can use here, that says: $$P(A \text{ or }B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\text{ and }B)$$

Do you see how this can be applied to your problem?

---

> PS: The origin of this formula.
>
> By the Additive Rule: The probability for the union of *mutually exclusive* events<sup>†</sup> equals the sum of the probabilities for each event.   († Also known as *disjoint* events.)
>
> Now, the events $A$ and $B$ are *not* mutually exclusive, *however* the events $A\cap B^\complement$ and $B$ are so; and these have the same union, $A\cup B$.   Likewise $A\cap B$ and $A\cap B^\complement$ are mutually exclusive and their union is $A$.
>
> $$\def\P#1{\mathsf P({#1})}\begin{split} \P{A\cup B} &= \P{(A\cap B^\complement)\cup B)}\\&= \P{A\cap B^\complement}+\P{B}\\ &= \P A-\P{A\cap B}+\P B \\[2ex] \P{A\text{ or }B} &= \P A+\P B-\P{A\text{ and }B}\end{split}$$
>
> This is a *very* handy formula to remember.

Comment: Thank you so much for the equation!

Comment: Ps: @HabinMoon Don't forget to click on the "accept answer" button .

Comment: Wow, @GrahamKemp, that's an awful lot of content to contribute to someone else's answer! Thank you :)